# Stopping the gcp instance regardless of region and zone

Tags: command-line-interface, gcloud, google-cloud-platform

I tried to stop a vm instances using

**gcloud compute instances stop instance-2-1**

It throws an error as follows:

**ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.stop) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/white-stacker-182910/zones/asia-southeast1-a/instances/instance-2-1' was not found**

I launched my instance in **asia-southeast-1-b**

I cant stop the instances in a specific region or zone except **asia-southeast1-a**

How can i stop an instances regardless of regions and zones.
Or  how can i stop an instance by specifying the region and zone along with it.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

**gcloud config set compute/zone asia-southeast1-a**

Then

**gcloud compute instances stop instances-2-1**

It will work.

Refer: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#set_default_zone_and_region_in_your_local_client

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the zone via flag

```
gcloud compute instances stop instance-2-1 --zone asia-southeast1-a
```

or via environment variable

```
CLOUD_SDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=asia-southeast1-a gcloud compute instances stop instance-2-1
```

useful when you have a terminal window dedicated to working on one zone, while another terminal for different zone.

As Ebins post mentioned you can also set global property for zone (it essentially adds --zone flag to each command)

```
gcloud config set compute/zone asia-southeast1-a
```

To stop `instance-2-1` in all/any zones

```
gcloud compute instances stop \
  $(gcloud compute instances list --filter="name:instance-2-1" --uri)
```